# How to concat two column by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

How can I concatenate columns and rows like this?

```
In:
  a  |  b  |  c  |  e
-----------------------
 mm    af    bn    nn
 pp    af    bn    yy

Out:

  b  |  c  |  final
------------------
af      bn    mm:nn&pp:yy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do column modify before `groupby` with `agg`

```
out = df.assign(final=df.a+':'+df.e).groupby(['b','c'],as_index=False).agg({'final':'&'.join})
out
Out[198]: 
    b   c        final
0  af  bn  mm:nn&pp:yy
```

Comment: Thanks, Beny. it's a correct answer. but I edit out. I want separate column by ":" char.